# Java generics unchecked override

Tags: java, oop

When implementing an interface method with generic type with a method with a concrete type (satisfying that generic type) unchecked override warning is taking place.

Here is a sample code :

```
interface SomeType{}

class Impl1 implements SomeType{}

interface SomeInterface{
    <T extends SomeType> T justDoIt();
}

class SomeInterfaceImpl implements SomeInterface{
    public Impl1 /*here i get the warning*/ justDoIt(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

warning says : return type requires unchecked conversion... Can anyone explain this. I know about type erasure but this is verifyable at compile time that there is no unchecked cast.

The important question. What is the right approach implementing this? given that I want to be able to implement SomeInterface but provide compile time Type safety of concrete type (not to use SomeType but concrete SomeType decendants)?

**UPDATE: here is what I want to do**

```
interface SomeType{

}

class Impl1 implements SomeType{

}

interface SomeInterface{
    SomeType convert(String param);
    String convert(SomeType param);
}

class SomeInterfaceImpl implements SomeInterface{
    public Impl1 justDoIt(){
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Impl1 convert(String param) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String convert(Impl1/*compile error right here*/ param) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope now my initial intention is clear. I need to provide generic interface for convertors...

Comment: `I know about type erasure but this is verifyable at compile time that there is no unchecked cast.` Wrong.  What if someone writes `instance.<Impl2> justDoIt()`?

Comment: Why do you need the method type parameter at all? Why can't you just have a method `SomeType justDoIt()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a generic type, not a generic method:

```
interface SomeType {
}

class Impl1 implements SomeType {
}

interface SomeInterface<T extends SomeType> {
    T convert(String param);
    String convert(T param);
}

class SomeInterfaceImpl implements SomeInterface<Impl1> {
    @Override
    public Impl1 convert(String param) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String convert(Impl1 param) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, you should ask yourself if using generics in that way makes sense in your special situation! Instances of `SomeInterfaceImpl` are only assignable to fields of type `SomeInterface<Impl1>`:

```
SomeInterface<Impl1> impl1 = new SomeInterfaceImpl();
```

You're NOT allowed to assign it to e.g. a variable of type `SomeInterface<SomeType>`:

```
SomeInterface<SomeType> doesntWork = new SomeInterfaceImpl(); // compile error
```

That means, your code is tied to `SomeInterface<Impl1>` everywhere you want to use your implementation. If that's ok, go with it.

Comment: While this resolves the compiling problems, the usage of `SomeInterfaceImpl` limits the clients to use `Impl1` always, which IMO should be avoided.

Comment: You're right. But it can still make sense, e.g. if an API needs a parameter of type `Converter<Date>` and you pass a `LongDateTimeConverterImpl`.

Comment: I understand your point but your example doesn't fit with this case. Why do you need to do that when using `Converter<Interface>`?

Comment: I just wanted to use the same names used in the question. But just rename `SomeInterface` to `Converter`, `SomeType` to `Number` and `Impl1` to `Integer` and you're almost there...

Comment: Again, I understand it but why would you have `Converter<Number>` and `Converter<Integer>` when they're not the same?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I've tried to address your concerns in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For the method return, just define the `justDoIt` method in the interface to return `SomeType`. Then in `SomeInterfaceImpl`, you can state that you're returning `Impl1` with no problem.

```
interface SomeInterface{
    SomeType justDoIt();
}

class SomeInterfaceImpl implements SomeInterface{
    public Impl1 justDoIt() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The Java Language Specification explains this (emphasis mine, comments added between braces []):

> [9.4.1. Inheritance and Overriding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.1)
>
> 9.4.1.2. Requirements in Overriding
>
> The relationship between the return type of an interface method and the return types of any overridden interface methods is specified in [§8.4.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3).

(...)

> [8.4.8.3. Requirements in Overriding and Hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3)
>
> If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides the declaration of another method d2 with return type R2, then d1 must be return-type-substitutable ([§8.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5)) for d2, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> [8.4.5. Method Result](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5)
>
> A method declaration d1 with return type R1 is return-type-substitutable for another method d2 with return type R2 iff any of the following is true:
>
> - If R1 is void then R2 is void.
> - If R1 is a primitive type then R2 is identical to R1.
> - If R1 is a reference type then one of the following is true:
>
>   - **R1, adapted to the type parameters of d2 ([§8.4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4)), is a subtype of R2.** [this is your case]
>   - R1 can be converted to a subtype of R2 by unchecked conversion ([§5.1.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9)).
>   - d1 does not have the same signature as d2 ([§8.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)), and R1 = |R2|.

---

For the method overriding, note that you have an invalid signature here, so you get a compiler error. It is not the same to have `String` argument and `Object` argument, and this is easily verifiable on method overloading:

```
class Foo {
    public void bar(String o) {
    }
    public void bar(Object o) {
    }
}
```

In this case, you **cannot** make such overriding, just declare the parameters as-is:

```
@Override
public String convert(SomeType param) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Oh crap shame on me :D